# extern variable not define but no error from compiler

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, extern, gcc-warning, linker-flags

I am compiling my .so library code and came across a weird problem.
In one the the header file i have decleared a variable extern that is included in other .c file and not defined any where.
Code compiles fine and while runtime it gives error.
Why no error or warning  at compile time ?
I  am using gcc 9.

Comment: Please include an [MCVE]. Please post a minimal example with all needed source code and post the gcc commands you are executing.

Comment: I think errors are reported while linking.

-Wl,--no-undefined linker option can be used while building shared library, undefined symboles will be reported as error.

Comment: but the issue is that my library has included other dynamic library headers and used many functions, if i use this linker flag "-Wl,--no-undefined" all those functions are also reported as undefined.Any solution that can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-Wl,--no-undefined` *and* specify the libraries where your functions come from on the command line. For example, if library `x` uses functions defined in library `y`:

```
gcc -shared -o libx.so x.c                        # OK
gcc -shared -o libx.so x.c -Wl,--no-undefined     # undefined symbols from lib y
gcc -shared -o libx.so x.c -ly -Wl,--no-undefined # OK again
```